# Fixing a div to the top on scroll - incorrect behavior in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an html page with a div in between the page and some content below the div. I want to fix this div to the top when I scroll past it. This is my HTML, CSS and JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('#dashfolio-main-row').offset().top)
      $('.dashfolio-content-dashbar').addClass('sticky');


    else
      $('.dashfolio-content-dashbar').removeClass('sticky');
  });

});
```

```css
.dashfolio-content-dashbar {
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: -7px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgb(45, 45, 45);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(45, 45, 45, 1) 0%, rgba(7, 7, 7, 1) 100%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(45, 45, 45, 1) 0%, rgba(7, 7, 7, 1) 100%, rgba(19, 19, 19, 1) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
}
.dashfolio-content-dashbar.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>hi</li>
  <li>hi</li>
  <li>hi</li>
  <li>hi</li>
  <li>hi</li>
  <li>hi</li>
  <li>hi</li>
  <li>hi</li>
  <li>hi</li>
</ul>
<div id="dashfolio-main-row" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-10 dashfolio-content-dashbar"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <!-- random content below -->
  <ul>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The middle div, which I have called a midbar, is centered on the page with the bootstrap column property. The expected behavior is, as soon as I scroll below the midbar, it sticks to the top, but it's horizontal position is unchanged. However, in my case, and **only in firefox**, the midbar moves horizontally to the right while sticking to the top when I scroll past it, and the content below the midbar flows over it and not below it. Please help me solve this issue. You can see exactly what I mean here - http://www.bootply.com/jOZjV5bFSV  (view in firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a couple of suggestions - because when you change an element to a position:fixed type - it removes it from the DOM - leading to your layout issues. So applying a text-center class on the parent div and some CSS style changes it is now doing the right thing. Try altering the following sections:

```
//change this section of the HTML
<div id="dashfolio-main-row" class="row text-center">
   <div class="dashfolio-content-dashbar"> </div>
</div>



//change this section of the CSS
.dashfolio-content-dashbar {
   width:80%;
   margin:0 auto;
}

.dashfolio-content-dashbar.sticky {
   position: fixed;
   top:0; 
   left:10%;
   z-index:999999;
}
```

Note that I am designating the width as 80% and then the class of sticky - setting the left to 10% to allow centering.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {

    $(window).scroll( function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('#dashfolio-main-row').offset().top)
            $('.dashfolio-content-dashbar').addClass('sticky');
         

        else
            $('.dashfolio-content-dashbar').removeClass('sticky');
    } );

} );
```

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

#dashfolio-main-row{text-align:center}
.dashfolio-content-dashbar {
  
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: -7px; /*removes gap between midbar and the vertical theme bar */ 
  border-radius: 15px;
   display: inline-block;

  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#2d2d2d+0,070707+100,131313+100 */
background: rgb(45,45,45); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(45,45,45,1) 0%, rgba(7,7,7,1) 100%, rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(45,45,45,1) 0%,rgba(7,7,7,1) 100%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(45,45,45,1) 0%,rgba(7,7,7,1) 100%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2d2d2d', endColorstr='#131313',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.dashfolio-content-dashbar {
 width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    

}

.dashfolio-content-dashbar.sticky {
 position: fixed;
 top:0; 
 left:10%;
 z-index:999999999;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li> hi </li>
   <li> hi </li>
   <li> hi </li>
   <li> hi </li>
   <li> hi </li>
   <li> hi </li>
   <li> hi </li>
   <li> hi </li>
   <li> hi </li>
</ul>
<div id="dashfolio-main-row" class="text-center">

   <div class="dashfolio-content-dashbar"> </div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
   <ul>
      <li> hi </li>
      <li> hi </li>
      <li> hi </li>
      <li> hi </li>
      <li> hi </li>
      <li> hi </li>
      <li> hi </li>
      <li> hi hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi </li>
      <li> hi </li>
      <li> hi </li>
      <li> hi </li>
      <li> hi </li>
      <li> hi </li>
      <li> hi </li>
      <li> hi </li>
      <li> hi </li>
      <li> hi </li>
      <li> hi </li>
      <li> hi </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @gavgrif! This works perfectly! Any idea as to why that flicker happens? In chrome, it's extra bad when I run it in my rails app.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue you are experiencing is because you are removing your col-md-10 div out of your row class div.

You will see here I am now adding your sticky to the row, and then using another div element to track the page offset for when to add the sticky.

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $(window).scroll( function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('#to-check-offset').offset().top)
        $('#dashfolio-main-row').addClass('sticky');         

      else
        $('#dashfolio-main-row').removeClass('sticky');
      });
} );
```

**CSS for sticky bit:**

```
#dashfolio-main-row.sticky {
 position: fixed;
 top:0; 
 width: 100%;
}
```

(note that I added width of 100% as well, this is because we are using fixed positioning, so the div element has no parent container to inherit width from, so we force it to 100%)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="to-check-offset">
  <div id="dashfolio-main-row" class="row">
     <div class="col-md-1"></div>
     <div class="col-md-10 dashfolio-content-dashbar"> </div>
     <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And a working code sample for both firefox and chrome:

http://www.bootply.com/jOZjV5bFSV#

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Heinrich! While your code works in the bootply fiddle, for some reason, it still doesn't in my rails app. I think it's weird and I tried for hours trying to get to the root of it to no avail. I will stick with @gavgriff's solution for now,  but appreciate your response! :D

Answer (score 0):

Increase the z-index to bring it forward.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

It doesn't seem to be moving to the right when I look at it.

Comment: Thanks @jlogan, looks like this only happens in Firefox! Can you please check in firefox, and if you have any solutions to it, please let me know? Thanks!